# MDX IIF Statement aggregation

Tags: mdx, olap, iif

I have a very simple IIF statement in my cube calculation to create a calculation called "Commissionable Units":

IIF([Measures].[Commission]>0, [Measures].[Unit Balance]*1, NULL)

At the lowest grain I get the correct result, but as soon as I aggregate at any level, I get incorrect results

Example:

> transaction #, Unit Balance, Commission, Commissionable Units
>
> 1, 500, 3, 500
>
> 2, 100, 0, 0
>
> 3, 250, 1, 250

When I remove the transaction dimension I get:

850, 4, 850

I should get:

850, 4, 750

I should mention that commission and units are in two different fact tables as they are different grains.